# pH of a solution of acetic acid and ammonium acetate

Tags: homework, physical-chemistry, equilibrium, ph

After studying ionic equilibrium, I was just making some wild questions and I was unable to calculate the $\ce{pH}$ of this solution. Assume, 1 mole of each was added to $1L$ solution of water.

My attempt :

$\ce{CH3COOH}+\ce{NH4OH<=>CH3COONH4}+\ce{H2O}$

This reaction will happen till all $\ce{CH3COOH}$ is consumed by $\ce{NH4OH}$. More of $\ce{NH4OH} $ will be formed by Le Chatelier's principle. So, the answer must be same as that of a weak acid and weak base salt : $pH=\dfrac{1}{2}(pK_w+pK_a-pK_b)$.
But how will we calculate if there was $2$ mole of acetic acid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some mistaken assumptions.

$\ce{NH4OH}$ and $\ce{CH3COONH4}$ are not molecules that exist.

The assuption "all $\ce{CH3COOH}$ is consumed" is incorrect.

Why do you say more $\ce{NH4OH}$ will be formed? How is this possibe? What can it be formed from?

Review that [Henderson–Hasselbalch equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henderson%E2%80%93Hasselbalch_equation)

Comment: $\ce{NH4+}+\ce{H2O<=>NH4OH}+\ce{OH-}$?

Comment: you mean + = -?

Comment: Well, that is : $\ce{NH4+}+\ce{H2O<=>NH4OH}+\ce{H+}$

Comment: Again, ammonium hydroxide isn't something that is stable. The two components undergo a large extent reaction to make ammonia. As a matter of fact, this is what Wikipedia has to say: "Ammonia solution, also known as ammonium hydroxide." 

So what Dave is suggesting is that you write the _net ionic_ equation, or in other words - the only right equation you can write for this system. Leave out the spectator ions to help you better see the chemistry.

Comment: @Awesome $\ce{NH3}+\ce{H2O<=>NH4+}+\ce{OH-}$ Again, $\ce{NH4OH}$ does not exist as a molecule.

Comment: So, how do we proceed to find out concentrations of acetic acid and acetate ion?

Comment: We start out by inventorying all the species in our system and then by considering all possible reactions. A systematic way to consider all possible reactions is to first start by reacting the strongest acid with the strongest base you have in the system (note that both the acid and base must be present in significant concentration, and at your initial molarity of 1, we can ignore things such as hydronium ion from the auto-ionization of water). Also don't confuse this with kinetics; reacting the strongest acid with the strongest base is just a bookkeeping method.

Comment: @Awesome, to a very good approximation, the concentrations of acetic acid and acetate will just be how much of each you add to the solution.  First you consider 1 mole of each, then you say what if I added 2 moles of acetic acid.

Comment: @DavePhD I want to consider both cases. Let me work on your advice.

Comment: @DavePhD Can you explain this assumption? Does ammonium acetate dissociate almost completely?

Comment: @Awesome Firstly, [ammonium acetate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_acetate) is not a molecule and fully dissociates. Secondly, you should look up the pKa of ammonium ion. You will see that at the pH the the acetic acid and acetate will establish, the ammonium will stay ammonium to an excellent approximation.

Comment: @DavePhD Thanks. I wonder what would be the order of its Ksp. If you find a link, please share. I am unable to find it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium pKa of ammonium is 9.25